# Why is it not possible to spoof referer and origin header with XHR?

Tags: web-application, same-origin-policy, header, referer

Technically speaking, it is possible to spoof both headers using an intercepting proxy but that's useless because we are doing it ourselves as an attacker.

When we send an ajax request using JS from another domain with our spoofed referer and origin header it won't really be spoofed. The browser would still send the legit header to the server.

My question is, why is it so that we can't spoof both these headers while sending cross domain requests?

Comment: Are you asking why these headers cannot be set (because the specification says so) or are you asking what the intend is that the specification says so (to prevent attacks)?

Comment: Because the browser says so

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "why"? It's simply a browser design decision. Browser vendors agreed that certain security restrictions should apply to certain headers.

Comment: Grandma uses a browser, not the command line. browsers disallow a lot of risky behavior to cut down on zombie attacks that command-line tools (for example) don't have to normally contend with.

Answer (score 6):

You can't set those headers, because the browsers ignore attempts to set them. Browsers ignore attempts to set them, because they aren't supposed to be script-controlled. The restriction on letting them be script-controlled is for security reasons. If you could set the Origin header, you could break the security guarantees of CORS. Since the whole point of CORS is to open gaps in the same-origin policy *for trusted origins only*, letting a script (which can be attacker-controlled) spoof the origin is obviously unsafe.

Another question would be: why *should* XHR/Fetch allow you to set those headers? What legitimate reason is there to do that? There's a good reason to disallow it (breaks a security guarantee, setting us back to the bad old days of JSONP where you couldn't be sure who sent the request), and no good reason to allow it, so of course it's not allowed.

Comment: Can you spoof them via a terminal executable, like bash? I tried and it actually works :/ `curl 'https://myapi.com/api' \
  -H 'authority: SPOOFED AUTHORITY' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'origin: SPOOFED URL' \
  -H 'referer: SPOOFED URL/' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'sec-gpc: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: MyUserAgent' \
  --compressed`

Comment: Obviously you can - HTTP is just text (OK, HTTP2 is binary, but that doesn't actually matter here); I can open literal `telnet` to a website and send whatever HTTP I want, including `Origin` and other headers. The OP actually alludes to this with their point about intercepting proxies. That's totally irrelevant to the question though, because the entire point is to get _the victim's browser_ to change these headers (because the victim's browser has the session and anti-CSRF tokens). You aren't attacking the server, here; you're attacking a _user_ so you need to do it through their browser.

Comment: I see. I had the impression that CORS was more of a safety measure for the server, but it is aimed to protect the client from some attack (which I still ignore how it would look like) if I understand you correctly. I guess is hard to prepare for something that you do not understand entirely...thanks for the clarification btw.

Comment: @nicoramirezdev You should go read about CSRF, but the short version is: imagine a website X that uses cookies for session authentication. That is, the user logs into X, the server generates a token (random/JWT/etc.), and sends it to the user in a cookie. The user's browser will send that cookie to the server for that site on every single request to X... no matter the source of the request (note: `samesite` is changing this). So if you're logged into site X and visit malicious site Y, a script on Y can force you, unknowingly, to take an authenticated action (e.g. send money to someone) on X.

Comment: if ur trying to protect or access control resources or assets on the server, then it is relevant. is there any way around this other than, say, using tokens for authentication?

Comment: it was addressed to you (hence i didnt tag anybody)

Comment: @oldboy It's still not clear what you mean by "then it is relevant". What is "it", and what do you mean by "relevant"? Also, literally everything where CORS origins matter is "trying to access control resources or assets". If you don't care who the user is at all - meaning the site's content is fully public to all users and there's no authorization controls at all - you can just slap `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on all responses. Won't work if there's cookies required, but that's because cookies are assumed unique per user. Or as the client site, you could scrape the target server-side.

Comment: 'it' referred to 'being able to spoof http headers'. im looking for a foolproof ways to prevent users from DLing assets while still allowing the client to render them. i know this can be achieved by using one-time-use tokens e.g. user visits page, server gets unused token from internal db, server embeds unused token in client-side code request to resource server, then resource server marks the token as used/invalid. im wondering if theres another way to accomplish this without using tokens that is equally or more simple or equally or less complex?

Comment: "im looking for a foolproof ways to prevent users from DLing assets while still allowing the client to render them" This is literally impossible, as has been covered many, many times before on this site. You can never make an authorized client that is _impossible_ for a user (who has access to said client) to spoof. This is also off-topic for this question; you could ask a new one but it'll likely get closed as a duplicate so I recommend just searching and commenting elsewhere if you don't understand the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

These headers cannot be modified as a safety precaution, the ability to alter them would break a lot of assumptions about how browsers work. There used to be some bugs in flash that would let you do this: https://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/441014/30/0/threaded